# Error while creating database in SQL server management studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have install SQL server management studio and while creating a database below mentioned error are occurring due to which I am not able to import my excel file. Can some one tell me what is the meaning of this error?

[image]

Comment: What is the SQL you're running to `CREATE` the database? Also, don't post images of error messages; there's a copy message button there, make use of it to post the error as text.

Comment: Its SQL server management studio

Comment: I asked what SQL you're running, not in what application.